# Ordering by multiple fields in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple table, something like: `int id, date created_at, date updated_at`. I'd like to order the rows so that any rows that have an `updated_at` will be sorted by that, and any that don't will be sorted by the `created_at`. The problem is that something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY updated_at, created_at
```

doesn't work. I've been looking at custom order clauses, something like:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHERE updated_at ISNULL <do something> END, created_at
```

but can't seem to get anything to work.
Help?

**EDIT:**
I should have specified that I want the `updated_at` fields to sort before the `created_at` fields. So, if the data looks like:

```
id  created_at  updated_at
--  ----------  ----------
1   2009-01-08  null
2   2009-09-08  null
3   2009-07-02  null
4   2009-09-05  2009-09-06
5   2009-04-01  null
6   2009-09-07  2009-09-08
```

I'd want results like:

```
id  created_at  updated_at
--  ----------  ----------
6   2009-09-07  2009-09-08
4   2009-09-05  2009-09-06
2   2009-09-08  null
3   2009-07-02  null
5   2009-04-01  null
1   2009-01-08  null
```

Comment: Updated my answer based on your update.

Answer (score 20):

looks like you're looking for:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(updated_at, created_at)
```

per [the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html), `coalesce` returns

> a copy of the first non-NULL argument.
>   If all arguments are NULL then NULL is
>   returned. There must be at least 2
>   arguments.

**Edit**: given the OP's edit, he may instead want:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(updated_at, '1929-9-9') DESC, created_at DESC
```

or similar tricks for DESC ordering; or maybe

```
ORDER BY MAX(COALESCE(updated_at, '1929-9-9'), created_at) DESC
```

it's impossible to tell exactly what the OP wants from a single and very peculiar example, but a variant on some one of these approaches should solve his actual problem, whatever that problem may actually be in specific, precise, and complete detail.

Answer (score 3):

IFNULL, see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull)

In this instance you'd use something like:

IFNULL(updated_at, '1-jan-2100'), created_at

All columns without an updated_at field would be given the default sort order and would then sort by created_at.  The value of 1-jan-2100 ensures they appear last in the list.  Change this to be 1900 if you want them first.

Comment: Thanks, that was super helpful, but it wasn't quite what I was looking for because I worded my question poorly. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question exactly, but it is an alternative solution.

If you were to set the `updated_at` field to the same as `created_at` on creation, you would always have a value for `updated_at` and could always just sort by the `updated_at` field.  For a minor amount of duplication you simplify your code, your life and the efficiency of your sql queries.